# Am I multitasking?

Tags: multi-tasking

When copying notes, Quite often I start to daydream all the while copying the notes word for word.
Is this multitasking ? I have been told that multitasking is not possible. And when copying notes my thoughts are not interrupted so I don't think I am switching between tasks.

Comment: Also note there is a distinction between _concurrent multitasking_ and _sequential multitasking_, which I outline [in an answer here](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/a/18225/21).